# Can I retrieve a list of object from database with spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-mvc, jsp

First time posting here, if there is anything missing, please tell.

I'd want to get a list of object from the db, however I don't know how to get the list as the controller only return string and the service is an interface, which can't be instanciated.

Bonus point: I'd add that in a scrollable menu with jsp, as of now I also don't know how.

Here's the relevant part:

Project architecture :

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───elearningmvc
│   │       └───spring
│   │           └───springhibernate
│   │               ├───controller
│   │               │       CategoriemoduleController.java
│   │               │       ChapitreapprisController.java
│   │               │       ChapitreController.java
│   │               │       Chapitre_formatchapitreController.java
│   │               │       FormatchapitreController.java
│   │               │       InvitationController.java
│   │               │       LocaliteController.java
│   │               │       ModuleController.java
│   │               │       RoleController.java
│   │               │       UtilisateurController.java
│   │               │
│   │               ├───dao
│   │               │       CategoriemoduleDao.java
│   │               │       CategoriemoduleDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       ChapitreapprisDao.java
│   │               │       ChapitreapprisDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       ChapitreDao.java
│   │               │       ChapitreDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       Chapitre_formatchapitreDao.java
│   │               │       Chapitre_formatchapitreDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       FormatchapitreDao.java
│   │               │       FormatchapitreDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       InvitationDao.java
│   │               │       InvitationDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       LocaliteDao.java
│   │               │       LocaliteDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       ModuleDao.java
│   │               │       ModuleDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       RoleDao.java
│   │               │       RoleDaoImpl.java
│   │               │       UtilisateurDao.java
│   │               │       UtilisateurDaoImpl.java
│   │               │
│   │               ├───model
│   │               │       Categoriemodule.java
│   │               │       Chapitre.java
│   │               │       Chapitreappris.java
│   │               │       Chapitre_formatchapitre.java
│   │               │       Formatchapitre.java
│   │               │       Invitation.java
│   │               │       Localite.java
│   │               │       Module.java
│   │               │       Role.java
│   │               │       Utilisateur.java
│   │               │
│   │               └───service
│   │                       CategoriemoduleService.java
│   │                       CategoriemoduleServiceImpl.java
│   │                       ChapitreapprisService.java
│   │                       ChapitreapprisServiceImpl.java
│   │                       ChapitreService.java
│   │                       ChapitreServiceImpl.java
│   │                       Chapitre_formatchapitreService.java
│   │                       Chapitre_formatchapitreServiceImpl.java
│   │                       FormatchapitreService.java
│   │                       FormatchapitreServiceImpl.java
│   │                       InvitationService.java
│   │                       InvitationServiceImpl.java
│   │                       LocaliteService.java
│   │                       LocaliteServiceImpl.java
│   │                       ModuleService.java
│   │                       ModuleServiceImpl.java
│   │                       RoleService.java
│   │                       RoleServiceImpl.java
│   │                       UtilisateurService.java
│   │                       UtilisateurServiceImpl.java
│   │
│   └───webapp
│       │   index.jsp
│       │
│       └───WEB-INF
│           │   spring-config.xml
│           │   web.xml
│           │
│           └───views
│                   categoriemodule.jsp
│                   chapitre.jsp
│                   chapitreappris.jsp
│                   chapitre_formatchapitre.jsp
│                   editCategoriemodule.jsp
│                   editChapitre.jsp
│                   editChapitreappris.jsp
│                   editChapitre_formatchapitre.jsp
│                   editFormatchapitre.jsp
│                   editInvitation.jsp
│                   editLocalite.jsp
│                   editModule.jsp
│                   editRole.jsp
│                   editUtilisateur.jsp
│                   formatchapitre.jsp
│                   invitation.jsp
│                   localite.jsp
│                   module.jsp
│                   role.jsp
│                   utilisateur.jsp
│
└───test
    └───java
```

UtilisateurController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/utilisateur/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUtilisateur(@ModelAttribute("utilisateur") Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateurService.saveUtilisateur(utilisateur);
        return "redirect:/utilisateur";
    }
```

LocaliteController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllLocalite(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("localite", new Localite());
        model.addAttribute("localiteList",
                this.localiteService.getAllLocalite());
        return "localite";
    }
```

LocaliteDaoImpl.java

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public List<Localite> getAllLocalite() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("From Localite");
    List<Localite> localiteList = query.list();
    return localiteList;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

there is some progress , it's not perfect as I can't access the object id right now but at least I got access to the list. ( got the name but the id is lost somewhere.) :

Code :

UtilisateurController

```
UtilisateurService utilisateurService;
        LocaliteService localiteService;
        RoleService roleService;
    
        public UtilisateurService getUtilisateurService() 
        {
            return utilisateurService;
        }   
        
        public LocaliteService getLocaliteService() 
        {
            return localiteService;
        }
        
        public RoleService getRoleService() {
            return roleService;
        }
    
        @Autowired
        public void setUtilisateurService(UtilisateurService utilisateurService) {
            this.utilisateurService = utilisateurService;
        }
        @Autowired
        public void setLocaliteService(LocaliteService localiteService) {
            this.localiteService = localiteService;
        }
        @Autowired
        public void setRoleService(RoleService roleService) {
            this.roleService = roleService;
        }
        
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/utilisateur", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getAllUtilisateur(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("utilisateur", new Utilisateur());
            model.addAttribute("utilisateurList", this.utilisateurService.getAllUtilisateur());
            model.addAttribute("localite", new Localite());
            model.addAttribute("localiteList", this.localiteService.getAllLocalite());
            model.addAttribute("role", new Role());
            model.addAttribute("roleList", this.roleService.getAllRole());
            return "utilisateur";
        }

@RequestMapping(value = "/utilisateur/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUtilisateur(@ModelAttribute("utilisateur") Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        System.out.println("affiche : ");
        System.out.println(utilisateur);
        this.utilisateurService.saveUtilisateur(utilisateur);
        return "redirect:/utilisateur";
    }
```

utilisateur.jsp :

```
            <tr>
            <td>
            <sf:label path="localite.ville"><spring:message text="localite.ville" />
                    </sf:label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <sf:select path="localite.ville" items="${localiteList}" itemLabel="ville" itemValue="ville">
            </sf:select>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

if you have any idea for add users in the "/utilisateur/add", it would help a lot, thanks.